# Can we assign same fields to different page layouts. How can we achieve this requirement

Tags: page-layout, visualforce

Can we assign same fields to different page layouts. How can we achieve this requirement. I have created few fields and assigned one page layout ( Account Lead), Now i want to assign the same fields to a different page layout ( Supply account). Please help me with this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In general, an option one always has is to "clone" an existing page layout and save it with a new name. You can then edit it to remove or add any fields you wish.

In the particular situation that you're describing, Supply Accounts would seem to have a different Record Type. You can create a unique Page Layout for displaying objects with that Record Type. That would easily be done when you specify a unique Record Type. You may want to look at creating Object Specific Actions which would help facilitate that. They're well covered in the [Force.com Fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) as well as in the Salesforce Help. Other references that may be useful to you would be the [Force.com Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/), [Tips and Hints for Record Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_recordtypes_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_recordtypes_cheatsheet/) and the [VisualForce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/).